# Did Christopher Paolini write any more Eragon books?

Tags: inheritance-cycle, christopher-paolini

Did he write any more books? The books I know are the 4 books, but in the last book he writes he isn't going to leave Alagaësia and is going to write more books! But here I am in 2019 and haven't heard about any more books!

Comment: I haven't heard about a sequel to the film either... :-(

Answer (score 4):

A book 5 is still in writing as far as I'm aware, he did a "recent", 18/09/2018, [Q/A about Book 5 on Paolini.net](https://www.paolini.net/2018/09/18/qas-book-5-future-stories-movie-reboots/):

> **DestinyWielder: Eragon and Saphira will not be main characters in Book Five, right? They will appear as minor cameos, yes? You have said that some element of Book Five has been set up in the previous books and nobody has guessed what it is, right?**
>
> Correct. Eragon/Saphira won’t be the main characters in Book V. And yes, I laid some groundwork for Book V in the previous books. Some has been spotted. Some hasn’t. It’s fun to see reader’s enthusiasm for guessing.

In the same interview he also comments further about what is planned after Book 5:

> **DestinyWielder: Are you going to write more books in the world of Alagaesia after Book Five is written? If the answer is yes, how many more books are you planning on writing?**
>
> Yes. How many? I have at least three planned, but they aren’t direct continuations in the way Book V will be. Ultimately, it’s going to depend on how long I live. Lol.

The [FAQ section](https://www.paolini.net/faq/) on his website also comments on a Book 5:

> **Will you write another book set in Alagaësia?**
>
> I did! *The Fork, the Witch, and the Worm*, a collection of short stories set in Alagaësia, was released on December 31, 2018! I also still have every intention of writing Book Five, which I have already outlined. After spending so long with the world and the characters of the Inheritance cycle, I can’t bring myself to walk away from them for the rest of my life. For more info, see this article.
>
> **Is The Fork, the Witch, and the Worm the long-discussed Book Five that you said you will write?**
>
> No. The Fork, the Witch, and the Worm is the first volume of a new series of short stories set in the world of Alagaësia. Book Five will be set after the events of this volume.

Comment: Are this books only on English or does it exist Swedish translated?

Comment: @Gabbelito [WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/title/the-fork-the-witch-and-the-worm/oclc/1080725243?referer=di&ht=edition) mentions a Swedish translation exists for _The Fork, the Witch, and the Worm_ and of course Book 5 is yet to be written.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the Inheritance Cycle, [Eragon's Guide to Alagaësia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Inheritance_Cycle#Eragon's_Guide_to_Alaga%C3%ABsia) and [The Fork, the Witch, and the Worm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fork,_the_Witch,_and_the_Worm) are books about Alagaësia. One of the short stories in the latter book is from Angela's perspective.

Comment: OP asked about stuff written by Christopher Paolini. The Angela story was not.

Comment: @ibid The original draft of the question included the line "I hope to know more about the witch(forgot the name now)", so that seemed like a relevant section to point out, even If it was technically written by his sister and only approved by Paolini.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I wasn't aware of the edit.

Answer (score 2):

He did. He's written a collection of short stories set after the *Inheritance Cycle*. Its called [*The Fork, the Witch, and the Worm*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/26152839-the-fork-the-witch-and-the-worm).